# How to add button to v-calendar | Vue.js?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I use [v-calendar](https://vcalendar.netlify.com/) package in my project. I want to customize input element. I want to add icon to right side of input element. I tried next code but there is no icon.

How to make such style: [link](https://codepen.io/PRtheRose/pen/BNgEJo)

```
<template>
<v-date-picker
    class='v-date-picker'
    mode='range'
    v-model='range'
    :show-day-popover=false
    is-double-paned
    show-caps>
    <button>
        <font-awesome-icon :icon="faInfoCircle"/>
    </button>
</v-date-picker>
</template>

<style scoped>
    .v-date-picker /deep/ button {
        color: green;
        font-size: 2.4rem;
        line-height: 2.4rem;
        vertical-align: middle;
        transition: color .25s;
    }
    .v-date-picker /deep/ button:hover {
         color: lightblue;
    }
</style>
```